# Как убрать подсказки в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Как убрать подсказки в Android Studio?

Когда курсором наводишь на текст который обведен желтым или красным волнистыми линиями. то появляется подсказка котороая почти перекрывает весь экран.

Желткого цвет подсказка. Как ее отключить. Бесячая хрень и постоянно из за этого виснет комп[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу отключить ее чтобы при наведении мыши она не работала. А нажатием Ctrl+F1 работала не знаю как сделать вообщем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java**.

И там отключите те подсказки, которые вам мешают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно отключить подсказки, нажав на картинку мужика справа снизу и передвинув ползунок на Syntax или вовсе включив Safe Mode, - это гораздо быстрее, чем в настройках **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java**, если нужно часто переключать режимы. [image: Окно Highlighting level]